# javascript width / height not functioning and colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/skarchmit/dndumodr/2/>
```

I usually get the javascript to work, but this simple action isn't working. (more code can be seen on JSFIDDLE.) NOTE: #PHOTOS IS attached to an UL

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function resize(){
document.getElementById('photos').width = "100px !important";
}
```

CSS:

```
#photos{
width: 500px;
display: block;
border: 2px solid red;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the css width, try this:

```
document.getElementById('photos').style.width = "100px";
```

Comment: That explains it a lot and why it wasn't working.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Document.getElementById('photos').style.width = "100px";

.width